# classList.contains('outputDiv') not supported in IE 9 and older,

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contains

`classList.contains('outputDiv')` not supported in IE 9 and older, is there any alternative for that?

My code is as below:

```
function toggleclass() {

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("outputDivs");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        if (elems[i].classList.contains("outputDivsDesigned"))
            elems[i].className = "outputDivs";

        else
            elems[i].className += " outputDivsDesigned";
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's a shim for older browsers (down to IE8) on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList#wrapper

Answer (score 3):

You can try this https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

or just use className, and search the returned string.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this, perhaps it might be helpful?

http://www.tjcafferkey.me/ie9-classname-containsclass-alternative/

It basically explains this simple alternative you could use:

```
function containsClass(yourObj, yourClass) {
    if(!yourObj || typeof yourClass !== 'string') {
        return false;
    } else if(yourObj.className && yourObj.className.trim().split(/\s+/gi).indexOf(yourClass) > -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would then run the function like this

```
var isFeaturedPost = containsClass(obj, 'featured-post-class');
```

**Edit: I've updated the function to check yourObj exists, and that yourClass is a string.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work as have not tested to be working for crossbrowser you can give a try to:-

```
  classList.indexOf("outputDivsDesigned") != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is `.contains()` functionality, search for the substring inside of the `className`, i.e. `elems[i].className.indexOf("outputDivsDesigned") > -1`.

So your function would look like this:

```
function toggleclass() {    
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("outputDivs");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        if (elems[i].className.indexOf("outputDivsDesigned") > -1)
            elems[i].className = "outputDivs";    
        else
            elems[i].className += " outputDivsDesigned";
    }
}
```